# Workplace council vote for spouse

Tags: ethics

We have a "staff council" at our workplace, that acts as a democratically elected body to represent worker's issues to management as well as help with social activities.

My spouse is running for election and is eligible for multiple positions (2 in this case) which we can vote for 2 candidates each.  In some cases I think they would be the best candidate.

It is permitted to vote for one's spouse, as well as the same person twice (once in each category) - but it feels a bit strange, desperate perhaps.

Do people see any problems with this, even if it is permitted by the rules?

The votes are anonymous to the electorate, except to the voting committee who would see that I had voted for my spouse (twice), since ballot is done by paper and is not anonymous.

Comment: It depends on whether you're allowed to vote for your wife.  Some votes discount being supported by close family members.

Comment: Do you believe you wife is the best candidate. If not, what do you value more, the best candidate in the council or peace at home.

Comment: Just to clarify, is seeming desperate your main concern? And, is it a secret or open ballot? And lastly, welcome to the Workplace!

Comment: What kind of workplace has pastoral activities?

Comment: @Lilienthal Workplaces that employ pastors, obviously....

Comment: @JoeStrazzere its voting for a person for two separate roles you only vote once for each role

Comment: You don't mention whether the vote is anonymous. That being said, this is clearly a personal issue. You need to decide whether you'll support her regardless of her qualifications, or whether you'll vote for the best person for the job. Once you've made that decision, the answer becomes clear.

Comment: And whatever you decide to do, make sure you tell your wife you voted for her twice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're allowed to vote for your wife, and you believe she'll do a good job, then vote.

If you have a separate vote for a separate position, then vote for that as well, if the voting process allows you to.

But first ask the people who are organising the voting about whether you're allowed to do this or not.

Comment: If its within the rules go for it.